# Is there a python module for the Linux "at" task scheduler

Tags: python, schedule, at-job

Lest I reinvent the wheel .... again:

Is there a python interface, API or module for the standard linux "at" task scheduler? I have tried searching the internet but searching for the word "at" is a tad bit useless :-)

My intention is to have a python script process same data and construct a shell file. Then use a subprocess call to have "at" schedule the job file for a specific date and time. I will have a similar function using "Schtasks.exe" if python detects it is running on windows. Lastly the python script exits ... leaving system scheduler the responsibility of running the job file.

update 1 July 2019:
Found an interesting "at" quirk.
The file called on the "at" command line (*i.e. the script or shell file*) does not need to be marked as "executable" in order to be run by "at".

For the record: I am running Linux Mint 19.1

Comment: Some options: `schedule`, `Celery`

Comment: standard module [sched](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html), external modules [schedule](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), [APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: I believe "schedule" would require the python script to be up and running 24/7. I would prefer to use the scheduler already built into the system.

Comment: previous_comment = previous_comment.replace ("schedule", "all of the above")

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with different approach:

- Write your python script.
- Call this script with a bash file.
- Schedule bash file with a crontab task.

Comment: My principle objection to cron is that "cron -e" invokes the system editor which is some incarnation of "vi" or "nano". Lastly cron is good for repeating tasks but running on a specific date is a bit cumbersome. "at" is much more suited for that.